# Append empty row to a dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to add an empty row to an existing populated Dataframe.
I am using the below procedure for this, but I do not want to see NA values in the empty row, just need some blank row.

Existing data frame:

```
abc
site control    test delta   pval  
1 US15376   3.15% 3.2% 1.59% 0.0022
```

empty matrix:

```
empty=matrix(c(rep.int(NA,length(abc))),nrow=1,ncol=length(abc))  
colnames(empty) = colnames(abc)  

rbind(abc, empty)
    site control test delta   pval  
1 US15376   3.15% 3.2% 1.59% 0.0022  
2    NA    NA NA  NA     NA
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: For this example, `df[2,] <- NA` will work and will maintain the data types. In general, this would be `df[nrow(df)+1,] <- NA`. If you are worried about outputting "NA" in some file, say csv, most output functions allow you to fill this value in. For example, `write.table` has an na argument which will fill in missing (NA) values with whatever character strings you want.

Comment: Awesome thank you, I found a way to avoid printing NA values in my output function (print). this worked. Thank you

Answer (score 53):

This one that was in the comments just worked perfectly for adding an empty row in my data frame:

```
#before

df

  site control    test delta   pval  
1 US15376   3.15% 3.2% 1.59% 0.0022

df[nrow(df)+1,] <- NA

#after

df

   site control test delta   pval  
1 US15376   3.15% 3.2% 1.59% 0.0022  
2    NA      NA    NA   NA     NA
```

Comment: One good things with this solutions is that it works with any number of row one wants to add using `df[(nrow(df)+1):newsize,] <- NA` which is pretty handy!

Answer (score 13):

```r
rbind(abc, NA)
```

as simple as that

Comment: I like this as it also is intuitively to change to rbind(NA, abc) if you want to add an empty row at the start of your dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

tibble´s *add_row* should do the job.
And if after that you want to get rid of NAs, one approach is to use dplyr´s *mutate_all*

```
library(tidyverse)

abc %>%
  add_row() %>%
  mutate_all(~replace(., is.na(.), ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version vor tidyverse that can be included in a pipeline:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  bind_rows(set_names(rep(NA, ncol(.)), colnames(.)))
```

On a more philosophical note, "appending an empty row" is something one might want to do when working with (other) statistical software, but I can't think of instances where it aligns well with R's way of doing things. In other words, while it can be done in R, I think that *if you are facing this problem, this points to more optimizing potential in your R workflow*.

Comment: Re philosophical note, today I wanted to insert things into a Google Sheets spreadsheet and leave some space inbetween things. `reframe(.by = Project)` with some blank lines at the bottom is imo, the correct and elegant way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `data.table`-object from the widely used package `data.table`, you can use a method of binding a copy of the last row with the original, and turning it into NA's.

```
dt <- rbind(dt, dt[nrow(dt), ])
dt[nrow(dt), ] <- NA
```

This can also be extended to insert the row of NA's to any spot:

```
i <- 5
dt <- rbind(dt[1:i, ], dt[i:nrow(dt), ])
dt[i, ] <- NA
```

The previously mentioned simpler method of using `rbind(dt, NA)` does not work when binding `data.table`-objects. You would need to define a new matrix, data.frame or data.table of row of NA's with the corresponding column names to the original table, but the above solution is easier.